# How to fetch changes from a forked repository which is a subtree

Tags: git, git-pull, git-subtree, git-fork, git-squash

So I have an issue wherein I forked Repository A to create Repository B.

Then I added Repository B into a subdirectory of Repository C via the `subtree` command as follows:

`git subtree add --prefix={SubdirectoryForRepositoryC} /remote-name {RepositoryBRemoteName} master --squash`

I had been using the following command to update the subtree:

`git subtree pull --prefix={SubdirectoryForRepositoryC} /remote-name {RepositoryBRemoteName} master --squash`

While I pulls changes from Repository B, it doesn't update Repository B based on Repository A and then pull those changes, which is what I need.

Effectively, is it possible to run a command within Repository C which updates Repository B based upon Repository A and then updates the Repository B subtree within Repository C?

Thank you so much!

Comment: What is `/remote-name` in your commands? I can't see it in any docs. Try to omit it.

Comment: The `/remote-name` is the URL of Repository B.

Comment: In that case, what is `{RepositoryBRemoteName}`? I believe you should user remote's URL or name, not both at the same time.

Comment: It is the remote URL of repository B.

Comment: What is then the difference between "URL of repository B" (`/remote-name`) and "remote URL of repository B" (`{RepositoryBRemoteName}`)? I believe there is only one possible remote URL of repository B and only this should be used in the command. I also don't understand why you use `{RepositoryBRemoteName}` in the `pull` command, because you intend to pull from repository A. So you should use `{RepositoryARemoteName}`.